# error:in ./src/main.js export default (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

CLI-3 working on my project and currently, I came across these errors, this is my first time using the Vuecli3  and I get this which makes my code not rendering on my screen.

error: WARNING in ./src/main.js  "export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";

//  Tailwind main.js
import "@/assets/tailwind.css";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";

// GSAP import
import gsap from "gsap";

// GSAP other plugins:
import Draggable from "gsap/Draggable";
import ScrollTrigger from "gsap/ScrollTrigger";
import MotionPathPlugin from "gsap/MotionPathPlugin";

// Vue-agile main.js
import VueAgile from "vue-agile";

// don't forget to register plugins
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger, Draggable, MotionPathPlugin);
Vue.use(VueAgile);
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(gsap);

new Vue({
 router,
 store,
 render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");
```

The screenshot is also here

[image: screenshot]

this is my code in the src/main.js folder
this is also what my package.json file looks like

```
  {
  "name": "gadgethub",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
  "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
  "build": "vue-cli-service build",
  "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
  "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.1.2",
   "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
  "core-js": "^3.6.5",
  "gsap": "^3.6.1",
  "postcss": "^7.0.35",
  "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.1.2",
  "vue": "^3.0.0",
   "vue-agile": "^1.1.3",
  "vue-router": "^3.5.1",
   "vuex": "^3.6.2"
   },
    "devDependencies": {
  "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
 "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
 "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
 "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
 "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
 "eslint": "^6.7.2",
  "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0"
 }, 
 "eslintConfig": {
   "root": true,
  "env": {
   "node": true
 },
 "extends": [
   "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
   "eslint:recommended"
 ],
 "parserOptions": {
   "parser": "babel-eslint"
 },
 "rules": {}
},
"browserslist": [
   "> 1%",
   "last 2 versions",
 "not dead"
 ]
```

}

Comment: What version of Vue shows in your package.json?

Comment: If you're using Vue 3 (a totally different thing to Vue CLI), you need to use `import { createApp } from 'vue'`. Vue 3 has no default export

Comment: I am currently on vue version 3.0.0 in my package.json